# XSL processing issue with java1.6

Tags: xslt

Below mentioned XSLT code works fine in java1.5 but fails in java1.6. I couldn't see any images in java1.6

Can someone provide solution for this?

```
<xsl:template match="item" mode="item-image">
    <xsl:param name="moduleParams"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="aBuilder">
        <xsl:with-param name="linkContent">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="images" mode="item">
                <xsl:with-param name="moduleParams" select="$moduleParams"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="images" mode="item">
    <xsl:param name="moduleParams"/>
     <!-- SOME OTHER CODE GOES HERE -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="img" mode="item-image"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img" mode="item-image">
     <xsl:variable name="class">
        <xsl:text>dummyclass</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

     <span class="{$class}">
        <img src="{@src}" width="{@width}" height="{@height}"/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

**RESULT HTML**

```
 <span>
    <img>
 </span>
```

**EXPECTED HTML**

```
  <span class="dummyclass">
    <img src="dummysrc" width="dummywidth" height="dummyheight"/>
  </span>
```

Why span and image element attributes are not coming when i am using java1.6? But it works fine when i use java1.5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to post minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT stylesheet and Java code to execute the stylesheet if you want us to help investigate the problem. Or consider to try your code with Java 1.6 but with a different XSLT processor like Saxon (http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding.xml) to check whether that gives the result you want. Even a test with the latest Xalan from apache.org might give better results.

Comment: How to know without input sample and complete content template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual suspicion with this kind of problem is that it's the XML parser in JDK 1.6 - it has some pretty weird bugs, and no-one seems interested in fixing them. So switching from the JDK parser to Apache Xerces is probably more likely to fix it than switching from Xalan to Saxon - but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your response michael. How can i switch from jdk parser to apache xerces. Is there any specific steps to follow

Comment: This reference probably tells you more than you need to know, but it should come in useful: http://people.apache.org/~edwingo/jaxp-faq.html